# Brackets Editor - disable automatic indentation?

Tags: adobe-brackets

When I press enter, I want the next line to have the same indentation as the previous line. Is this possible in brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Debug` on the top menu of Brackets.

Go down to `Open preferences file`.

Click on it.  A huge text file pops up that has all the brackets preferences.

Control F and find `smartIndent`.

Change the true field to false.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On Linux, you'll have to open a terminal and type "sudo brackets" to launch with root permissions so you can modify the preferences file... Also, on my machine changing the defaultPermissions file didn't work. I had to make a project preferences file (brackets.json).

Answer (score 2):

Open Brackets

Click Debug -> Open Preferences File

Edit brackets.json which appears in the right window pane.
Add:
,
"smartIndent": false

Hit CTRL+S to save and the indenting no longer takes place.

Comment: I actually cant change it from true to false, wouldnt let me type or delete.

Answer (score 1):

Set the "smartIndent" field in the preference file to false.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible. Setting smartIndent = False doesn't seem to work. It will still indent a new line after a new tag.